# How to Check if Matrix is Circular / Target Matrix?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, matrix, while-loop

*Enter **N** (dimension of square matrix) such that N is **odd** and in interval **[1,100]**. For entered matrix, check if it is a **target matrix**: if yes, print YES; if no, print NO.*

***Target Matrix** is a matrix that is organized in concentric circles starting from the centre. Each concentric circle has -1 the value of the previous one. Examples:*

[image]
and
[image]

---

I've tried approaching this problem by using a `while` loop to increase the `radius` which starts at centre increases. inside, I've used two `for` loops to go through that part and check if the values are according the the rule given above.

I'm not really sure if this is a good approach. Do you have some suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 100

int main() {

    int matrix[DIM][DIM];
    int N;
    int targetMatrix = 1;
    int matrixCenter;
    int radius;

    do{
        printf("Enter N: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        if (N % 2 == 0 || N < 1 || N > 100){
            printf("Invalid value of N.\n");
        }

    } while (N % 2 == 0 || N < 1 || N > 100);

    // Matrix Entry
    printf("Enter the matrix: ");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    // Value at Center
    matrixCenter = matrix[N/2][N/2];
    radius = 1;

    // (N - 1) / 2 is the distance from center of matrix to its side
    while (radius <= (N - 1) / 2) 
    {
        for(i = N/2 - radius; i <= N/2 + radius; i++){
            for(j = N/2 - radius; j <= N/2 + radius; j++){
                if (i == N/2 && j == N/2) // Center Value
                    continue;
                if (matrix[i][j] != matrixCenter - radius)
                    targetMatrix = 0;
            }
        }

        if (targetMatrix == 0){
            printf("NO: This is not a target matrix"); // If not a target matrix
            return 1;
        }
        radius++;
    }

    printf("YES: this is a target matrix"); // If it is a target matrix

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's fine, but a bit verbose.  for (i=0; I<N; ++i) for (j=0; j<N; ++j) if (m[i][j] != m[N/2][N/2] + max(abs(i - N/2), abs(j - N/2)) { printf("NO!"); return; }  print("YES!"); ought to work as well.

Comment: You are testing too many values : for each radius you test a full submatrix (except it’s center) instead of testing first  and last row and first and last columns or comparing with theorical value it should have.

Comment: @PtitXav Yeah, I've realised that. I'm just not sure how to test only the 'shell' values of that submatrix/

Answer (score 0):

Testing shell of submatrix only :

```
int first = N/2 - radius;
int last = N/2 + radius;
for (int i = first; i <= last;i++) {
    // first on last line: increment by one
    // other : increment by radius * 2
    for (int j = first; j <= last;j += ((i==first)||(i==last) ? 1 :radius*2)) {
        // test i,j here
    }
    
}
```